# How to send xml to soap in Android

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap

I try to access a soap web service from Android. This soap service required login method. i need send password and username for retrieve data. I am write this code but it is not working.

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.kxml2.kdom.Element;
import org.kxml2.kdom.Node;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SoapTestActivity extends Activity {
     final static String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com/";
     final static String METHOD_NAME = "login";
     final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com/login";
     final static String URL = "http://dgpysws.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis?wsdl";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SoapObject reSoapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        Element usernameTokenElement = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "loginMessage");

        Element passwordElement = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "Password");
        passwordElement.setAttribute(NAMESPACE, "v", "*****");
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, passwordElement);

        Element usernameElement = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "UserName");
        usernameElement.setAttribute(NAMESPACE, "v", "*****");
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernameElement);



        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.headerOut=new Element[1];
        envelope.headerOut[0]=usernameTokenElement;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(reSoapObject);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport=new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try {

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject soapObject=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

            Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "Response: "+soapObject);


        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




 <ns1:login xmlns:ns1='http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com'>
    <loginMessage>
    <Password v='*****' />
    <UserName v='****' />
    </loginMessage>
    </ns1:login>
```

How to  am i build and send this above xml in android.

Edit: Error Messages

```
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soap.test/com.soap.test.SoapTestActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at com.soap.test.SoapTestActivity.onCreate(SoapTestActivity.java:54)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-27 12:57:09.932: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: and what is the error message? You need to give more details if you want somebody to help you.

Comment: ok, probavly you recive some error message from the webservice on this line :  SoapObject soapObject=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; Most probably the message you send is not in the correct format and the webservice return error, which cannot be casted as SoapObject

Comment: I think i am make mistake. I create wrong xml with elements. How to i build it correct?

Comment: I just gave a hint. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980108/android-ksoap2-setting-the-namespace-for-nested-children-types link for ex. Also you can set androidHttpTransport.debug = true; and look at the androidHttpTransport.requestDump and responseDump to see what is happening

Comment: I need to develop complex type in android.
<xs:element name="login">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="loginMessage" nillable="true" type="dgp:LoginMessage"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="LoginMessage">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" nillable="true" type="dgp:StringValue"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserName" nillable="true" type="dgp:StringValue"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

Answer (score 0):

I am solving problem with use httpclient.I will not use ksoap2 for android. I will use androidHTTPclient with AsyncTask.