# KSOAP ANDROID - Sending Complex Object - Object has ObjectMember

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

Does anybody know a solution to send as a parameter an Object having Object has member ?
I tried to do something like this :

---

```
public abstract class ContractObject implements KvmSerializable {
    public ContractObject() {
    }

    public abstract void fill(SoapObject soapObject);

    public Object getProperty(int intPropertyIndex) {
        Object val = null;
        try {
            val = this.getClass().getFields()[intPropertyIndex].get(this);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(val != null) {
            if(val.getClass().isPrimitive()) {
                return val;
            }
            else {
                return ((ContractObject) val).toPropertyInfo();
            }
        }  else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return this.getClass().getFields().length;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int intPropertyIndex, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        Field field = this.getClass().getFields()[intPropertyIndex];
        info.name = field.getName();
        info.type = field.getType();
    }

    public void setProperty(int intPropertyIndex, Object objectPropertyNewValue) {
        Field field = this.getClass().getFields()[intPropertyIndex];
        try {
            field.set(this, objectPropertyNewValue);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public PropertyInfo toPropertyInfo() {
        PropertyInfo value = new PropertyInfo();
        value.setName(this.getClass().getName());
        value.setType(this.getClass());
        value.setValue(this);
        return value;
    }

}
```

---

But it always end with some :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: Client: Client@416802f0

---

My Test Object Look like that :

---

```
public class Order extends ContractObject {
    public int id;
    public Client client;
    public SoapArray<ProductType> contentProductType;
    public DeliveryType deliveryType;
    public PaymentType paiementType;
    public boolean isTracked;
    public Address deliveryAddress;
    public Address billingAddress;
    public String comments;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think your real problem will be send the `SoapArray<ProductType>` as a member of `Order` class.

Answering to your question: have you use `addMapping`? Take a look at this: [Android Ksoap2 Setting the namespace for nested (children) types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5980108/434171)

Comment: It does not work ^^
the formated xml contains n0:ContractObject as the server expect ContractObject...